# Помощь с указателями

Tags: c++, c

Дошел до темы указателей, поэтому сразу вопросы:

1)

```
    char *lo = "12345";
    char *plo = lo; // вот так можно, это понятно
    // но почему можно так? 
    char **plo = lo;
    или так
    char **plo = *lo;
```

2. Что тут происходит и почему так можно делать?

```
    main() {
      char *lo = "12345";
      fun(lo);
    }
     
    // так
    void fun(char s[]){ // немного не понимаю, почему так делается
      printf("%s", s); 
    }
     
    // или так
    void fun(char *s){ // так понимаю
      printf("%s", s);
    }
     
    //можно и так
    void fun(char **s){ // так тоже не понимаю
      printf("%s", s);
    }
     
    //тоже не проблема
    void fun(char **s[]){ // ну а это вообще факинг щит какой-то
      printf("%s", s);
    }
```

А главное все варианты работают...

3)

```
   main()
   {
  

     char *err[] = {
      "Cannot Open File\n",
      "Read Error\n",
      "Write Error\n",
      "Media Failure\n"
     };
     fun(err);
   }
    
   void fun(char *s[]){
     printf("%s", s[0]);
   }
```

Понимаю, если бы написали

```
    void fun(char **s){
      printf("%s", s[0]);
    }
```

Но почему char *s[] работает, я не понимаю. Главное, если в main так попробую написать

```
main(){
*perr[] = err; 
}
```

то работать не будет..

Comment: ша придет и ответит AnT из силиконовой долины

Comment: А кто вам сказал, что так char **plo = lo; можно? Студия ругается, между прочим...

Comment: А вот блокс нет... вечно из-за этих компиляторов проблемы. Спасибо, буду знать)

Comment: **Работает** или **компилируется**? Как начинающий, вы просто **обязаны** любое предупреждение компилятора рассматривать как ошибку. А компилятор, который тот же код их первого вопроса пропустит без предупреждений - или выкинуть, или изучить. как его заставить выдавать все предупреждения...

Comment: У вас там скорее всего gcc? Настройте так, чтоб выдавал все предупреждения, и все предупреждения трактовались как ошибки! Я ничуть не шучу - у вас пока недостаточно опыта, чтоб понимать, какое предупреждение можно пропустить, а какое - нет.

Comment: `-Wextra` какой-нибудь... Я бы ещё посоветовал `-Wpedantic`

Comment: @Harry не знаю, меня всегда раздражал ворнинг на конструкции вида `if (a = some_function())`

Comment: @pavel асигн в условии?

Comment: @pavel ты ворнинг-то читал?

Comment: @Herrgott я знаю что он значит. Меня раздаражет необходимость писать лишние скобки `if ( (a = some_function()) )` чтобы компилятор молчал.

Comment: @pavel ты значение возвращаемое функцией назначаешь в переменную `a` в условии, понимаешь? Не нужно пытаться обмануть линтер/компилер. `==` != `=`

Comment: @pavel Откровенно - я предпочитаю написать явное `((a=...) != 0)` (даже не просто лишние скобки). Не скажу, что убираю **все** предупреждения, но по максимуму - всегда. А уж для начинающего это обязательно. А то вот так вот, пардон, и в Чернобыле - отключили раздражающую защиту...

Comment: @Herrgott я же уже написал что понимаю :D

Comment: @pavel тогда причин для раздражений нет?)

Comment: @Harry да у нас на 1 курсе был спор с преподавателем. Он требовал чтобы компилятор не выдавал предупреждений. Пришлось ключик прописать, он был в ступоре.

Comment: Господа, какой в итоге компилятор посоветуете, чтоб я больше не вводил людей в заблуждение и не задавал похожие вопросы. 
p.s Есть линукс и есть Win, какой лучше для какой ОС?

Comment: @non_grata на любителя. я g++ люблю тот что mingw. многие clang. можно на visual studio (но аккуратно). Вообще советую под линукс и что-то из g++/clang.

Comment: Разумеется Visual Studio, там хоть отладчик нормальный есть...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов и чем вам в codeBlock отладчик не нравится?) С g++ компилятором...

Comment: @pavel А у них там полностью свой отладчик? Или-таки gdb-шное что-то?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для начала давайте разделим понятие "работает" на "работает и все ок", "компилируется и вроде работает", "компилируется, но происходит что то странное".

Второе, разделим с и с++. Многие считают, что с является подмножеством с++. Но это далеко не так. На данный момент, это языки, которые имеют просто много общего.

Начнем с самого главного, которое справедливо для с/с++

```
a[b] == b[a] == *(a+b)
```

То есть, эти все три выражения эквивалентны. Когда в следующий раз увидите `1[a]` - не пугайтесь, это нормально, хоть и не очень применимо для продакшн кода.

Отсюдова второе следствие, если закрыть глаза на некоторые особенности, то массив это и есть указатель. И в большинстве случаев `*a` == `a[]`.

Теперь разберем примеры.

```
char *lo = "12345";
```

в си - это почти ок. В с++ это плохо, так как `"12345"` - это `const char*`. А присваивание с потерей константности это плохо.

```
char *plo = lo; // вот так можно, это понятно
```

конечно можно - `char*` и `char*`

```
// но почему можно так? 
char **plo = lo;
```

а так как бы нельзя. И с++ будет ругаться, потому что с одной стороны `char**` , а с другой `char*`. Но для с это два указателя и он закрывает на это глаза.

```
или так
char **plo = *lo;
```

Опять же, для с++ компилятора тут ужас - попытка присвоить типу `char**` значение типа `char` Но на низком уровне все ок. Указатель это просто int, char - это просто то, что может быть приведено. Компилятор си доверяет человеку.

Поехали дальше.

```
main() {
char *lo = "12345";
fun(lo);
}
```

по поводу типа я уже писал. там явно не хватает const.

```
// так
void fun(char s[]){ // немного не понимаю, почему так делается
printf("%s", s); 
}
```

`char[]` это просто массив. А массив это указатель.

```
// или так
void fun(char *s){ // так понимаю
printf("%s", s);
}

//можно и так
void fun(char **s){ // так тоже не понимаю
printf("%s", s);
}
```

тут формально все ок. Потому что printf будет  трактовать s как `char*`. как я сказал выше, `char*`, `char**` это все просто int. Вызывающая функция сохранила адрес, а printf его извлек.

```
//тоже не проблема
void fun(char **s[]){ // ну а это вообще факинг щит какой-то
printf("%s", s);
}
```

Здесь снова никаких "проблем". `char** s[]` - это просто `char***` и снова тот же int. Пример сводится к предыдущему.

поэтому, и пример ещё ниже - `char* s[]` это `char** s`.

```
main(){
*perr[] = err; 
}
```

а вот это точно не будет работать - код не валидный, типы переменных не известны (хотя может они где то и спрятались). Но! написать в левой части `*perr` - это нормально - это разыменования указателя. И эта звездочка не должна обманывать - это звездочка разыменования, а не объявления типа указателя. И квадратные скобки в этом случае лишены смысла. Но если бы там был индекс, то сразу ситуация улучшается.

В целом, си старается быть недалеко от ассемблера. Поэтому подобные конструкции в си и работают. С++ старается быть более строгим и проверяет детальнее.

Comment: Спасибо большое, много нового узнал для себя. Добра Вам и позитива!